# Enterprise Architect - Decision block and DEPENDENCY

Tags: design, change-management

I would like to ask for help with activity diagrams in EA and decision block (branching).

Lets assume we have simplified activity diagram with decision block "Is working day today?" with 2 branches "Yes" and "No".

Lets assume that we need to change it to "Is working day or saturday today?"

I am supposed to add to the diagram "Change" element describing a change, which is required to be implement and to "link" this change to all affected blocks of Activity diagram.

Is is OK to link Change with Activities/Actions. But the issue is that "Decision" element cannot be linked with Change in any direction.

In other words I am trying to find workaround for "red arrow", which cannot be "drawn" in EA
[image]

Colleagues suggested workaround using Action duplicating Decision block, but I do not like any duplication in code or diagrams.

[image]

Please advise an elegant way hot to overcome duplication and still linking Change element to all elements which are affected by the change.

Comment: Leave the action but delete the text on the decision block? Photoshop it? Just do something quick and dirty, this is not worth your time and effort, and getting it "perfectly" right is of no value to anyone in your company. Just make sure that the message is communicated clearly, otherwise it's just busywork.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @FilipMilovanović here.  Your goal shouldn't be "correctness of a diagram," it should be "correctness of the software."  Do the diagram well enough to understand what the software needs to do, and don't worry about it being strictly "correct."